# What keyboard shortcuts should I use to make a selection of 1,000,000 lines of code out of a total of 14 million lines of code with Visual Basic?

Tags: visual-studio

I have a ".txt" file of 14 million lines of code and I would like to select and cut the first 1,000,000 lines of code with visual studio. What is the key combination that I have to use to make this selection.

PS: I tried to make this selection with the classic methods, like:

- `Ctrl + Shift + ↑`
- Classic selection with the right click of the mouse, then drag down.

But they are so chronofages and I can not get by with these methods.

Comment: You have a single source code file with 14 million lines of code?  Run man, run.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found how to do it, just do:

1. Put the cursor on the first line of code;
2. Then click on the button **"GO"** in the menu, when the drop-down menu will appear then click on the button **"Go to Line / Column ..."**, then enter the number of the line to which you want to land and type on "Enter" on your keyboard. You will be redirected to this line of code.
3. Then press **"Ctrl"** + **"Shift"** and make a click on the line of code where you are, it will automatically select from line of code 1 to the line of 1,000,000 (In my case).